# UIWebView stuck in Portrait mode when placed in a secondary view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, xcode4.2

I have an odd problem. When I run UIWebView in a single view application it runs fine, e.g. when the phone rotates the webView rotates to keep the view upright. However, if I add a new view to the application and open that view with a button on the main view, the webView in the secondary view is stuck in portrait mode.  It doesn't stay upright when I rotate the phone.  The only difference between the UIViewControllers is that one is the main view and one is a new view called by the main view.

Here is my code for switching to the second view:

```
- (IBAction) nextPlotButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Next Plot");
    NextViewController *subClass = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    subClass.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    subClass.view.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
    [self.view.superview addSubview:subClass.view];

    //ARC
    nextView = subClass;

}
```

And here is my code for after the second view is loaded

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scatterPlot" ofType:@"html"] ;
    NSURLRequest *localRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath]] ;
    [webView2 loadRequest:localRequest] ;
    [self.view addSubview:webView2];
}
```

Thanks for the help!
Cheers,
Jason

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use -presentViewController: instead of adding the view as a subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `-presentViewController:` instead of addSubview and that should solve the problem. Interface orientation is handeled by root viewcontrollers, so adding a subview wont have the correct rotation.